# sum() query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, window-functions

I want to show up the result of the equation in sql :

```
A : 
0.5
0.25
1
1
1
```

I need to take a current row and divide it by the sum of rows, For ex: 0.5/3.75

I tried this but shows me an error :

```
select A / sum(A) 
from table X
```

Comment: A represents a column in a table,

Comment: You need a windowed `SUM()`.

Answer (score 3):

The way you've used SUM is as an aggregate function. You can't blend row-level and aggregate values in one line.

In most databases, SUM can also be turned into a windowing function with the OVER clause, which I think will do what you want. Try this:

```
select A / sum(A) OVER () AS ratioValue
from tableX
```

Answer (score 1):

Just window that `SUM()`:

```
select a / sum(a) over() as ratio from mytable
```

Expression `sum(a) over()` computes the sum of `a` over the whole table, and makes it available in each and every row.

On the other hand, `sum(a)` (without the `order by`) is an aggregate function, that can only be used in the context of `group by` (either explicit or implicit). Typically, this query gives you the total sum:

```
select sum(a) as sum_a from mytable
```

If we were to use this and not use window functions, we would re-phrase your original query like so:

```
select a / (select sum(a) from mytable) as ratio from mytable
```

But of course it is much simpler and more efficient to use the window sum here.